# Separate correctly blobs in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-morphology, binary-image

I'm writing code that should detect Hebrew letters.
This is my initial image:

[image]

The 2 letters (ע and נ) are connected, and thus I can't identify them correctly.

So I use dilation to separate them:

```
ker = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
dilated_img = cv2.dilate(ci.astype('uint8'), ker, iterations=3)
```

After the dilation the image looks like that:

[image]

The problem with the second image is that the dilation caused to more than 2 connected components.
So my question is how could I take separately the 2 images of the letters, with the additional black components that were added due to the dilation process.

so what I need to take is:

[image]

and:

[image]

separately.

important comment:

In this case the letters were connected vertically. They can be horizontally connected as well.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: where did you get that "initial image"? maybe you can improve something int he steps befor?  you could simply omit small components . I don't know Hebrew but I guess you don't need those small dots.  other than that, why do you detect letters using this approach?

Comment: You can try iterations number change. Try iterations=1 or iterations=2.